# Date values from text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two text fields with dates. I want to convert them to excel dates and subract one from the other
eg:

```
cell 1: Wed 18 Feb 2015 18:00
Cell 2: Mon 16 Feb 2015 07:00
```

Giving 59 hrs (`59:00:00` will do)

I believe this is correct but I get a `#value!` result which I guess is because B5 does not have the correct excel date time value.

Please advise

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(B5,5,2) & MID(B5,8,3) & RIGHT(B5,4)) + TIME(MID(B5,17,2),MID(B5,20,2))
```

Comment: What is the value in B5?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your values quite easily, e.g. with this formula in D5

`=MID(B5,5,20)+0`

format as required, e.g. custom format as `ddd d mmm yyyy hh:mm` and they'll look as before but this time they'll be "true" date/times as far as excel is concerned so you can simply subtract one from the other to get the difference, i.e. with converted values in D5 and E5

`=E5-D5`

format result cell as `[h]:mm:ss` to get `59:00:00`

or do the conversion and subtraction in one cell with this formula

`=MID(C5,5,20)-MID(B5,5,20)`

format result cell as `[h]:mm:ss` as before

see examples of that latter approach [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awa0qq56n44jlfe/Time_difference.xlsx)

Comment: Thankyou for your excellent and speedy response.
After wasting so much time on official Microsoft sites, I’m truly in awe of this caring community!!!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of items. I assume the values listed as dates are in Excel as Strings. If you have them as Dates this would be a lot easier.

There are two problems with your `DATEVALUE` functions. First the values being extracted are wrong. These are the values from the first string:

```
MID(B5,5,2) = 18
MID(B5,8,3) = Feb
RIGHT(B5,4) = 8:00
MID(B5,17,2) = 18
MID(B5,20,2) = 00
```

Secondly the `DATEVALUE` expects to a parse a string. So you need separators. For example:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(B8,5,2) & "-" & MID(B8,8,3) & "-" & MID(B8,12,4))
```

NOTE: This approach is fragile because it assumes the format of your timestring. It will break if any of the values don't line up.

Once you get proper Excel dates you can use the following formula to calculate the time span in hours between the two

```
=INT(B5-B6)*24 + INT(MOD(B5-B6,1)*24) &" hours"
```

This will give `59 hours` for your date.

Comment: Thankyou for your excellent and speedy response.
After wasting so much time on official Microsoft sites, I’m truly in awe of this caring community!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with your formula, but it's a little more complex than that.  For this type of scenario, I usually end up breaking it into a number of helper cells to reduce the complexity, although you could consolidate it all if you like.  Assuming your date/time value in A1:

```
Cell  Formula                                         Result
A1    Wed 18 Feb 2015                                 18:00
B1    =MID(A1,8,3)&" "&MID(A1,5,2)&", "&MID(A1,12,4)  Feb 18, 2015
C1    =RIGHT(A1,5)                                    18:00
D1    =TIMEVALUE(C1)                                  1/0/00 18:00
E1    =DATEVALUE(B1)+D1                               2/18/2015 18:00
```

Then do your date/time math on the values on E1.

Here's a combined, single cell version of the formula:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,8,3)&" "&MID(A1,5,2)&", "&MID(A1,12,4))+(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,5)))
```